# rewrite rule causing 500 error

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule. I didn't write it so I'm not sure what I should change.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I know that problem lies with this line

```html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php
```

When I delete that part everything works, but i assume the coder included it for some reason, so what is wrong with it?

I am running this script in a subdomain.

I have no update the line to the following

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]+)/$ /$1.php
```

Not sure it can be done like this. ubt i see it has to do something with `(-)` it has to be at the end.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php`

and checked it against the code and it looks ok on a rewrite rule checker. Try adding `[L]` . You may need to define that.

Comment: that doesn't seems to work as it gives me again a 500 error. I am using cpanel and mod_rewrite is always enabled so i guess the problem is also not there.

Comment: Try this tool: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - its an excellent tool to check your rules.

Comment: good tool but it didn't gave me a clue way it is not working. They do not support the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} and that was the only thing tht was wrong with it.

Comment: Right now i am seeing in the apache error log the following 
line RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\\s]+)/$'